# Unable To Copy JSON To Clipboard Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, webflow

A friend and I have poured through countless questions on here and tried multiple solutions, but nothing we seem to try will work.

This is the closest we have gotten, but you will see in the console log that all the JSON is turned into a random set of characters.

```js
var panels = document.querySelectorAll("[copy-wf='true']"); // Find All Elements With This Attribute
for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    panels[i].addEventListener("click", copyWF);

document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
  
  e.clipboardData.setData('application/json', wfComponent);
  e.preventDefault();
 
document.removeEventListener('copy', e);
  
});

function copyWF () { document.execCommand('copy'); };

var wfComponent;
  
  // const uuid = document.getElementById("copyBtn").getAttribute("uuid") - Alternative For This Is Below
  
const uuid = document.querySelectorAll('.wfbtn').forEach(elem => console.log(elem.getAttribute('uuid')));
// Scroll Through The Console Log, This Code Works To Grab Each UUID, But The JSON Goes All Wonky

  fetch('https://ucarecdn.com/' + uuid + `/` + `.json`) // Build Link To JSON File, Using UUID Attribute Value
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => wfComponent = data)
  .then(() => console.log(wfComponent))

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.wfbtn {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Component #1: <br> <br>

<button class="wfbtn" id="copyBtn"  copy-wf="true" uuid="0b3312b6-bcb8-47a4-963d-ee8cff851c3f">Copy Webflow Component</button>

<br> <br>

Component #2: <br> <br>

<button class="wfbtn" id="copyBtn"  copy-wf="true" uuid="3f1f3195-ec51-4d93-b98e-d70c25418fc0">Copy Webflow Component</button>

<br> <br>

Component #3: <br> <br>

<button class="wfbtn" id="copyBtn"  copy-wf="true" uuid="2277d37b-44e1-48b2-949c-eb4d322bb468">Copy Webflow Component</button>
```

Comment: `.forEach()` returns `undefined`. You then use that to set `uuid`. `uuid` is used to create a url that is unlikely to be understood by the server. The server returns an image in response which is the binary you're seeing in the logs.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so quickly! That's what I thought was the issue as well. But, when I run the code in Codepen, the uuid for all three buttons is successfully pulled and added to the logs.

Comment: Then the code you have on codepen is different from the code you have here.

Comment: Here's the link to the codepen if that helps: https://codepen.io/nocodebenny/pen/wvmRdYg?editors=1111.

If you scroll to the top of the logs, you'll see the uuid is being grabbed from each button. There are no errors coming up in codepen either, which is especially why I feel stuck.

Comment: It seems to be the same code, behaves the same, and has the same issue. It still stands that you're setting `uuid` to `undefined` in your javascript. `.forEach` always returns `undefined` regardless of what you use it for. (That the correct uuid prints to the console is irrelevant in this case. `console.log()` returns `undefined` as well.) You probably want `const uuid = panels[i].getAttribute('uuid');` instead. You'll probably also need to fix how you build the url since that doesn't look right either.